# Modify some href links on a page using Javascript

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, url-rewriting, href, dom-events

I would like to change every link on my page held by the class .btn_view

My links on my page are like :

```
<a class="btn_view" href="/download/documentA.pdf">VIEW</a>
<a class="btn_view" href="/download/documentB.pdf">VIEW</a>
<a class="btn_view" href="/download/documentC.pdf">VIEW</a>
...
```

into

```
<a class="btn_view" href="viewer.html?file=/download/documentA.pdf">VIEW</a>
<a class="btn_view" href="viewer.html?file=/download/documentB.pdf">VIEW</a>
<a class="btn_view" href="viewer.html?file=/download/documentC.pdf">VIEW</a>
...
```

I am working on this piece of code, but I can't figure out the issues :

```
const items = document.getElementsByClassName(".btn_view");

items.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) //Loop through your elements
    {
        //Verify that the href starts with /download/
        if (items[i].href.indexOf("/download/") === 0)
        {
            // add viewer link in front of original url
            items[i].href = "viewer.html?file=" + items[i].href
            //If it does, open that URL in a new window.
            window.open(items[i].href, "_blank");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: If you put a relative url into `href`, that will be resolved, so `/test/` will be turned into `localhost/test/`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you changing on `events` just loop through and change it here is how .

```js
function modifyLink(){
var items = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_view");
for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
 let href = items[i].getAttribute("href");
 console.log(href);
 items[i].setAttribute('href','viewer.html?file='+href);
 
}
for(var i=0;i<items.length;i++){
 console.log(items[i].getAttribute("href"));
}
}

modifyLink();
```

```html
<a class="btn_view" href="/download/documentA.pdf">VIEW</a>
<a class="btn_view" href="/download/documentB.pdf">VIEW</a>
<a class="btn_view" href="/download/documentC.pdf">VIEW</a>
```

Comment: consider accepting the answer if you are satisfied with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to do it using event listener :

```js
const items = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_view");

Array.from(items).forEach(item => item.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
  let href = item.href.replace(location.origin, "");
  if(href.indexOf("/download/") === 0) {
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open( "viewer.html?file=" + href, "_blank");
  }
}));
```

```html
<a class="btn_view" href="/download/documentA.pdf">VIEW</a>
<a class="btn_view" href="/download/documentB.pdf">VIEW</a>
<a class="btn_view" href="/download/documentC.pdf">VIEW</a>
```

But I would recommand to do like this :

```js
const items = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_view");

Array.from(items).forEach(item => {
  let href = item.href.replace(location.origin, "");
  if(href.indexOf("/download/") === 0) {
    item.href = "viewer.html?file=" + href;
  }
});
```

```html
<a class="btn_view" href="/download/documentA.pdf">VIEW</a>
<a class="btn_view" href="/download/documentB.pdf">VIEW</a>
<a class="btn_view" href="/download/documentC.pdf">VIEW</a>
```

In this case links are static and you don't need to handle event

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is that you use a `class` selector here:

```
const items = document.getElementsByClassName(".btn_view");
```

this will not yield the tags having the `class` of `btn_view`. You will need either:

```
const items = document.getElementsByClassName("btn_view");
```

or

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll(".btn_view");
```

The second problem is that even though `getElementsByClassName` returns an array-like object with DOM elements inside, you intend to define an event handler for all its `items`, but instead of assigning it to the `items`, you assign it to the container of the `items`. So:

```
for (var item of items) {
        //Verify that the href starts with /download/
        if (item.href.indexOf("/download/") === 0)
        {
            // add viewer link in front of original url
            item.href = "viewer.html?file=" + item.href
            //If it does, open that URL in a new window.
            window.open(item.href, "_blank");
        }
}
```